# Python 3 How to delete images in a folder

Tags: python-3.x, delete-file

How do I delete all png format pics in a folder using Python 3?

Comment: Did any of these answers resolve your question?

Answer (score 20):

This single line statement will take each file in a specified path and remove it *if* the filename ends in `.png`:

```
import os
os.remove(file) for file in os.listdir('path/to/directory') if file.endswith('.png')
```

Comment: +1 for `os.remove()`, but I suggest not to use the `file` identifier for the purpose. It actually is a `filename` or `fname`. Moreover, even though the `file` lost the meaning it had in Python 2, it may be still confusing to use the identifier for another purpose.

Comment: I could not get os.remove() to work as described: 
>>> os.remove(kml_fn) for kml_fn in os.listdir(kml_owner_directory) if kml_fn.endswith('.kml')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    os.remove(kml_fn) for kml_fn in os.listdir(kml_owner_directory) if kml_fn.endswith('.kml')

Comment: Hi, I am using python 3.8. Got error: statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But in my case, I need to wrap this code into the generator like [...]

Comment: You also need to provide the full path: `os.remove(os.path.join('path/to/directory', file))`

Answer (score 4):

```
import glob
removing_files = glob.glob('file path/*.jpg')
for i in removing_files:
    os.remove(i)
```

replace file path with the directory to the image folder

Comment: there's a space between `removing` and `files`. this answer is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 2):

this function will help you to delete a single image file all you need to do is put it in for loop to delete the multiple images or file..just double check that you are providing valid path to your file.
'

```
def remove_img(self, path, img_name):
    os.remove(path + '/' + img_name)
# check if file exists or not
    if os.path.exists(path + '/' + img_name) is false:
        # file did not exists
        return True
```

'

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.